# SQL solution to overlapping timeframes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a group of machines. They run and stop occasionally. These run times are recorded into a postgres table automatically with timestamps `starttime` and `endtime`.

I need to find the run time per machine in a 6 hour period. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT machine, SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (endtime - starttime)))
FROM table
WHERE 
      starttime >= '2016-01-27 12:00:00'
      AND starttime <= '2016-01-27 18:00:00'
GROUP BY machine
ORDER BY machine
```

So this works, I get the run time in seconds by machine over that time period. BUT it has a flaw - any run times that started before 12:00 do not get counted. And any run times that started in my time frame but don't end until after it have time counted that shouldn't be there.

Is there a solution to ONLY extract the time that is inside the time frame? My initial thought would be to select all rows where:

```
endtime >= '2016-01-27 12:00:00'
```

and somehow, in memory, set all the start times at `'2016-01-27 12:00:00'` 
where the start time is earlier than that and:

```
starttime <='2016-01-27 18:00:00'
```

and, again in memory without updating the database, set all end times to `'2016-01-27 18:00:00'` where the end time is later than that. and then run the extraction/summation query.

But I'm struggling on how to implement something like this. I have a working solution in Java/Python this data is returned to, but they are iterative and take more time than I'd like. I'd really like to find an SQL solution to this if possible.

Edit: To clarify, I need to count ALL run time that **occurs within the time frame** - if a run starts before the time frame only the portion of that run that occurs after the time frame should be counted.

Comment: Simply start between ts1 and ts2 OR end between ts1 and ts2?

Comment: is it specifically between those times every time?

Comment: @Takarii no, the timeframes are specified by the user. jarlh That would short time counted both on the beginning and the end - I need to count all run time that occurs within this timeframe, regardless of when it started or stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : this is what you need.

When it start between the range, and ends after, it will calc it as ended at 18:00:00.

Same goes for when ended between the range and start before, it will calc as it started at 12:00:00

```
SELECT machine, SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (endtime - starttime)))
FROM (SELECT machine,
             case when starttime <= '2016-01-27 12:00:00' then '2016-01-27 12:00:00' else starttime end as starttime,
             case when endtime>= '2016-01-27 18:00:00' then '2016-01-27 18:00:00' else endtime end as endtime,  FROM table
    WHERE 
          (endtime>= '2016-01-27 12:00:00'
          AND endtime <= '2016-01-27 18:00:00')
          OR   (starttime>= '2016-01-27 12:00:00'
          AND starttime<= '2016-01-27 18:00:00')
GROUP BY machine
ORDER BY machine
```

Comment: The problem is if the run started before the time frame I need to count the portion of the run that is within my time frame. But not the portion that is before the timeframe starts. Same on the ending side - only the portion of the run that is within the timeframe should be counted.

Comment: Still having trouble understanding, you want only those who started AND ended in the timeframe? or those who only ended in the timeframe? Or...? say it like this and i'll write it in the code @ErikN

Comment: So if my start time is `'2016-01-27 12:00:00'`, if I had a run that started at `'2016-01-27 11:55:00'` and ended at `'2016-01-27 12:05:00'`, only 5 minutes should be added to the time. Same on the end - if my end time is `'2016-01-27 18:00:00'` and I had a run that started at `'2016-01-27 17:55:00'` and ended at `'2016-01-27 18:05:00'` it would also only add 5 minutes.

Comment: @ErikN You see, this is why you need to give us sample of input and output.. Now this should work. :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do better with the explanation next time. Just a small typo, the comma after the second case clause doesn't need to be there, and postgres complains that the inner table needs an alias. But these are both minor things, your solution is working great :)

Comment: My main work with sql in with ORACLE dbms:) So i assume its reasonable that there are a few syntax problems:P @ErikN anyways, no problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overlaps operator:

```
SELECT machine, SUM(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (endtime - starttime)))
FROM table
where (starttime, endtime) overlaps (timestamp '2016-01-27 12:00:00', timestamp '2016-01-27 18:00:00')
GROUP BY machine
ORDER BY machine
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the type [tsrange](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html) and its [intersection](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) operator.

Example data:

```
create table machines (machine int, starttime timestamp, endtime timestamp);
insert into machines values
(1, '2016-01-27 10:00:00', '2016-01-27 14:00:00'),
(2, '2016-01-27 15:00:00', '2016-01-27 16:00:00'),
(3, '2016-01-27 17:00:00', '2016-01-27 20:00:00');
```

This query returns time frames *rounded* to the given period:

```
select 
    machine, 
    tsrange(starttime, endtime)* 
        '[2016-01-27 12:00:00, 2016-01-27 18:00:00)'::tsrange t
from machines;

 machine |                       t                       
---------+-----------------------------------------------
       1 | ["2016-01-27 12:00:00","2016-01-27 14:00:00")
       2 | ["2016-01-27 15:00:00","2016-01-27 16:00:00")
       3 | ["2016-01-27 17:00:00","2016-01-27 18:00:00")
(3 rows)
```

Get the aggregate from the above dataset:

```
select 
    machine, 
    sum(extract(epoch from (upper(t) - lower(t))))
from (
    select 
        machine, 
        tsrange(starttime, endtime)* 
            '[2016-01-27 12:00:00, 2016-01-27 18:00:00)'::tsrange t
    from machines
    ) sub
group by 1
order by 1;

 machine | sum  
---------+------
       1 | 7200
       2 | 3600
       3 | 3600
(3 rows)
```